# How to read content from http 200 response from server built using python flask?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I used python flask function send_file to send image file from server to client. I get Http 200 response from the server with headers containing content information and ***response.text*** returns string of bytes.  Currently both server and client is in local system. I want to access the file and save it in client side.
Server code:

```
@app.route("/ss", methods=["POST"])
def ss():
    return send_file("chap.jpg",attachment_filename="chap.jpg")
```

Client code:

```
payload = {"image": image}
r = requests.post(http://127.0.0:5000/ss, files=payload)
print(r.text)
```

I tried converting the string from r.text to numpy array and save the array as jpg but i get TypeError for bad argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the [binary content of the response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) and save it to a file.

```
with open('myfile.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: solution works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you want to upload file ? {"imagge" : image is not a solution do like me :

```
import requests

image = 'image.jpg'

payload = {'image':(image, open(image, 'r'),'multipart/from-data')},

url = 'http://127.0.0:5000/ss'

r = requests.post(url, files=payload)

print r.text
```

Comment: No, I want to download the file sent from the server